# Jest fails because Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to run component test on React app with jest and failing with below error. But the application is working fine normally

```
 FAIL  src/__tests__/app.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Target container is not a DOM element.

       7 | import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
       8 |
    >  9 | ReactDOM.render(
         |          ^
      10 |     <React.StrictMode>
      11 |         <Provider store={store}>
      12 |             <App />

      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26091:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.tsx:9:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.tsx:6:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/app.test.tsx:45:1)
```

Here is my App.tsx file.

```
import React from 'react';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Message } from '@library/queues';

const App: React.FC = () => {
   return (
     <ThemeProvider theme={'dark'}>
      // routes
     </ThemeProvider>
   )}

export default App;
```

Here is index file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.scss';
import App from 'App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from 'redux/store';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

and finally the test file

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
    render(<App />);
    const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
    expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I have verified many links and tried different ways but all leads to this error only. I am using one private npm module and mapped that using `moduleNameMappers` and sometimes that also throws error.

```
moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@library/queues(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1', -- working without errors but throwing errors when we run tests
        // '^@library/queues(.*)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/$1', -- throwing errors
        '\\.(css|scss|jpg|png)$': '<rootDir>/empty-mock-module.js',
    },
```

Could somebody helps me whether I'm doing correct or not. I need to know how to map node_modules libraries in code. All the npm modules are working except my private module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the App is rendered in Jest it cannot find the 'root' element so one solution I have found is to provide a div element when the 'root' doesn't exist.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root') || document.createElement('div')
);
```